# SQL save data to file

Tags: sql-server, save, load

I'd like to save data from an SQL Server database table to a file, then load it into another database that has the same table already created in it

How can I do this?

I know there should be some simple way of doing it, but Stack Overflow search and Google aren't yielding good answers (or I'm not asking a good question).

Comment: Just google for Linked server

Comment: Thanks, but I was thinking of a couple of dirt-simple 1-line scripts - 1 to save, 1 to load.

Comment: Is this a one time data dump or do you need to transfer data on a regular basis?

Comment: Just one time. I want to populate a test database for dev purposes.

Comment: Although in the future I may want to make it on a regular basis, so I can write unit tests that test on current data. But for now I just want something simple to get the dev effort going.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the Import/Export Wizard.  Right click on your database in Management Studio and look for import data and export data under the tasks item.

Answer (score 1):

Check [bcp utility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187042.aspx) and [BULK INSERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx) statement.

Answer (score 1):

the [bcp utility and BULK INSERT as mentioned by @Lukasz Lysik](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1422541/sql-save-data-to-file/1422579#1422579) are good for moving lots of data.  However, [sp_generate_inserts by Narayana Vyas Kondreddi](http://vyaskn.tripod.com/code.htm#inserts) allows for many filtering options of the data, and good when there isn't that much data.